# CSS - 2 background images and positioning

Tags: css, image, background, position

I have looked online for the answer and can't find how to add two images and position them with the same css element

my code looks like

```
div.coupon {
  background-image: url(slice.png), url(notice.png);
  background-position: center, right bottom; 
}
```

I can make it work with just the (slice.png) but when I try to add (notice.png) it erases both of the images. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

Not very easy (for cross-browser support anyways)...you'll need to get creative with some trickery...

This method also allows you to get more creative with css3 animations for each image, etc.

Here's a super simple workaround example to get your started:
http://jsfiddle.net/XGrzZ/

HTML:

```
<div class="background-1">
    <div class="background-2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-1 {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background:rgba(34,35,55,0.1); //replace with image
}
.background-2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: rgba(90,39,68, 0.3); // replace with image
}
```